# What is the future of LISP? Should I learn it?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I know this is not a very technical question, but it's for all technical people, that's why I ask it here.  Here is my question:

Can someone help me understand the current and future of learning LISP? One of my papers in university uses LISP for a project (it's a big project - may be two semester long), and I am not able to decide whether I should put lots of effort into learning LISP if there is no future in LISP, or should I just learn as much as needed for the assignments and do some other project which doesn't need any LISP. I know a little bit of basic LISP. Please help me.

Comment: I'm a Lisper myself, but I'm voting to close this since there's no objective way to answer the question.

Comment: There is an objective way to answer the question. The future of Lisp is that it will go on, and likely a relatively small number of people world wide will continue to use it. There is unlikely to be a sudden boom.  If you don't know Lisp, then you're oblivious to a big area of computer science with a rich history, and way of computing. That goes beyond concerns about putting language names on your resume and getting work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a real interest in software development, you should learn Lisp and other programming languages.

Ruby, Python and Perl are distant relatives of Lisp. A bit nearer is Javascript - which is basically a primitive Lisp with a strange non-programmable syntax.

The core of Scheme is relatively clean and quite powerful. Teaches basic concepts.

Common Lisp is a powerful language which has all kinds of 'exotic' extensions. You can experience multi-paradigm programming in a single language.

Clojure is a newer Lisp which breaks with the Lisp tradition in multiple ways, but offers an interesting blend of a functional language and concurrency.

All three Lisp dialects offer meta-linguistic abstraction capabilities that few languages offer in such an elegant way (Prolog would be another interesting language that has similar capabilities).
Experiencing that code is data and data can be code will change your view on programming forever.

Answer (score 22):

Lisp is one of those languages that really changes the way you think about programming. If by value you mean marketability, it has very little value. If you mean value as in what it gives you as a developer, I would say that it is quite a bit higher.

Answer (score 8):

Lisp's been cooking along for over 50 years. If it was going to die it would have died a long time ago.

Modern languages are *still* catching up to Lisp.

"It's not dead, it just smells funny" as someone once said (only my Google-fu fails in finding a citation).

Answer (score 5):

Some of the features that we take for granted in new languages had their origins in Lisp. ([This article](http://www.paulgraham.com/diff.html) has more information on this). Languages [continue to borrow](http://blog.vmathew.in/invokedynamic) ideas from Lisp. Lisp's biggest advantage is its ability to represent *code as data and data as code*, which most of the 'popular' languages cannot accommodate because of their convoluted syntax. Lisp remains at the forefront of programming language research, and the next *earth shaking* language will be closer to Lisp than to anything else! So a knowledge of Lisp programming will keep you ahead in the game.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a lot of value in LISP and currently we see a kind of Lisp renaissance, with new languages like clojure. Even Python and Ruby are very lispy under the skin.

Also the concepts learned in LISP often transfer over to other languages and will make you a better developer whatever language you use on the day job.

Answer (score 1):

If you learn Lisp (not LISP :) you will become a better programmer overall. If you are in university, I believe it would be a good investment of your time.

There is a lot of movement in Lisp lately (Clojure, etc...). Maybe it might be used more in commercial in future. I hope so. Lisp is fun!

Comment: lisp is one of the few languages I would jump ship from ruby professionally for. I am excited by the recent buzz too, and really hope it does take off

Answer (score 1):

#### It has no commercial future but learn it anyway

You aren't fully educated in computer science until you know Lisp.

---

If Lisp was going to catch on it would have done so, you know, in the last 50 years or so. You can disregard the people saying that Lisp implementation #127 is going to finally catch on.

Still, it is so unique and powerful that it should be well worth your time to understand it.

Comment: Virtually every time somebody has told me "if XYZ was going to catch on it would have done so by now", they end up looking silly when it actually does catch on.  :-)  I agree you can ignore specific instances of "this time for sure!", but if Lisp never dies (and it shows no indications of doing so), then eventually somebody might make one that's good enough to 'catch on'.

Comment: The CL Standard should have been renewed but I think with clojure we have a very good and pragramtic lisp on our hands that can be comercialy applied.

Comment: Well, certainly it's *possible* that a combination of faster CPU's, more memory, and, ok, something like Clojure will finally find a niche. And with the whole world going digital there are possibly more niches now than ever before. But Clojure can't do some of the things that Ruby and Python can (start quickly, be useful for scripting) and so I think the killer version of Lisp is not here yet. Clojure should be great on a server but it can't replace the existing vaguely Lisp-like scripting languages.